# What is the range of the Gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, gamma-function

I know from the product definition $\Gamma(z)=\frac{e^{-\gamma z}}{z}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^{-1}e^{z/n}$ that it has no zeros. Is $0$ the only value omitted by $\Gamma$? I guess another way of looking at the question is that $\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$ is an entire function, so (by little Picard) omits at most one complex value; so the question is whether this function is surjective or whether it omits one complex value (if the latter, do we know which one)?

I have seen a [similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/300466)  for Riemann's zeta function answering that $\zeta$ is surjective, but I haven't been able to find anything for the Gamma function (my motivation is that I just learnt little Picard so I'm reviewing several basic functions from complex analysis, like all the trig functions, exponential, etc and trying to know the ranges of more of these functions).

Comment: I don't get it. Why can't you apply little Picard to $\Gamma$ to deduce it only omits $0$?

Comment: @mathworker21 $\Gamma$ is not entire

Comment: @user580918 Thanks. Another stupid question. I have confused myself. The function $e^{e^z}$ is entire (I think) and omits the values $0,1$. Why doesn't this contradict little Picard?

Comment: @mathworker21 umm it doesn't omit the value $1$. $e^z=2\pi i$ has solutions, so $e^{e^z}=1$ in that case

Comment: @user961409 thanks. im not that smart

Comment: Why don't you try the same argument that worked for $\zeta$?

Comment: @SungjinKim I looked at the first proof mentioned there, and for $\zeta$ it uses some nice symmetry properties (commuting with complex conjugation). For $\Gamma$, I'm not sure that it enjoys such nice properties; i.e I don't think $\overline{\Gamma(z)}=\Gamma(\overline{z})$, or that $\Gamma(-z)=-\Gamma(z)$ (this is usually how I'd try to check what are candidate values that could be missed). The second proof in the link uses the Hadamard factorization theorem (which I don't know), but that seems to be specific to functions having only one pole, while $\Gamma$ has infinitely many.

Comment: Try Schwarz reflection principle for $f(z)=1/\Gamma(z)$.

Comment: @SungjinKim could you elaborate? $\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$ is already entire, so I don't see how Schwarz's reflection principle (which is about extending holomorphic functions on half a domain to the other half) is relevant

Comment: As $1/\Gamma$ is entire, doesn't Picard apply? And if you know the range of $1/\Gamma$, don't you know the range of $\Gamma$?

Comment: Sorry to keep interrupting, but how does that MO answer know that $1/(\zeta-c)$ has order $1$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, $\frac{1}{\Gamma}$ is entire, but I do not know if its image is $\Bbb{C}$, or if it omits one value (and if so which one... though this is a secondary concern for me)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note first that Picard theorem is valid for meromorphic functions in the plane with the statement that they can omit at most two values (finite or $\infty$); if the function is entire it obviously omits infinity, so one gets the usual statement about omitting at most one finite value.

In this case, as $1/\Gamma$ is entire hence omits infinity, so obviously $\Gamma$ omits zero and since $\Gamma$ is conjugate invariant it can omit at most another real value (if it would omit a complex non-real, it would omit its conjugate etc).

But the image of $(0, \infty)$ under it is $(1, \infty)$ and then looking on the negative axis we have that $\Gamma$ is negative on $(-2k-1,-2k)$ and positive on $(-2k-2, -2k-1)$ and going to the appropriate infinity at the ends; letting $a_{k}=\Gamma(x_k)<0$ the maximum of it on $(-2k-1,-2k)$ and $b_k=\Gamma(y_k)>0$ the minimum on $(-2k-2, -2k-1)$, one has that $b_{k+1} \le \Gamma(x_k-1)=a_k/(x_k-1), k \ge 1$ so since $|x_k-1| >3$  as $k \ge 1$ one has $b_{k+1} < |a_k|/3$

Similarly $|a_{k+1}| \le |\Gamma(y_k-1)|=b_k/|y_k-1| \le b_k/3$ which imply that $a_k, b_k \to 0, k \to \infty$ so $\Gamma$ cannot omit any other real value, hence its image is $\mathbb C \cup \infty - 0$

Comment: I'll have to verify the details later, but this is perfect. It seems like your third paragraph is just formalizing what the graph of the Gamma function on the negative real axis looks like (that it's a bunch of alternating $\cup$ and $\cap$ shapes which get closer and closer to the horizontal axis). Embarrassingly, the thing I missed is that $\Gamma$ is conjugate invariant because I looked at the $e^{\gamma z}$ term in the product and for some reason convinced myself the exponentials do not commute with conjugation (when in fact they do since their power series has real coefficients only).

Comment: yes that's correct - the function makes lower lows (in absolute value) on each unit interval on the negative axis and they are exponentially decreasing so it is easy to prove it